# Design an opposite layout + loop from data from database

Tags: html, css, database, loops, layout

My Objective: is to both design a layout that has an image floated to the right and text to it's left, then another section that is the opposite which will be an image to the floated to the left and it's text to the right. Like the picture attached.

I'm doing this using a while-loop querying data from my Database
using this code:

```
       // establish a connection
        $db     = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        // run sql
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `solutions` WHERE 1 LIMIT 6";
        // run query
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        // echo '<pre>'.var_export($result, TRUE).'</pre>';

        // check query
        if($result){
            // echo '<pre>'.var_export($row, TRUE).'</pre>';
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '
                <span class="solution">
                    // this section floats right
    <div style="background-image:url('.$row['img_thumbnails'].'); " class="solution-img"></div><a href="solutions.php?key='.$row['solution_key'].'"><h2>'.$row['name'].'</h2></a>
                        <p>'.$row['headline_title_hook'].'</p>
                        </span>';
            }

        }else{
            trigger_error('SQL has an error');
        }
```

Problems I faced were to format the code to do this layout attached.

[an opposite layout looped from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnRWY.png)

Comment: Hey there. "In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself." and "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I figure the solutions which was a line of css

```
.solution-wrapper .solution-left{ width:50%; float: left; clear:both; }
```

.solution-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .solution-left{float:right;}

I thought it had to do with PHP or something coming from the Database, however it's simple css selector trick.

Thanks https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/#